# Java enum which contains map internally?

Tags: java, java-7

I have below enum. I need to get the description by code. I have below code. It is working but can it be improved still?

```
public enum Maps {

    COLOR_RED("ABC", "abc description");

    private final String code;
    private final String description;
    private static Map<String, String> mMap;

    private Maps(String code, String description) {
        this.code = code;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }


    public static String getDescriptionByCode(String code) {
        if (mMap == null) {
            initializeMapping();
        }
        if (mMap.containsKey(code)) {
            return mMap.get(code);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void initializeMapping() {
        mMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Maps s : Maps.values()) {
            mMap.put(s.code, s.description);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You question makes no sense. What do you want exactly?

Comment: Your question is probably more appropriate here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I just need whether my enum is proper and can it be improved..

Comment: Move this Question to Code Review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/